# Вывести пользователю список покупок

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, task

Просьба помочь начинающему, пробовал кучу вариантов, но тема со списками никак не хочет укладываться в голове.

Имеется:

```
cook_book = [['салат',[['картофель', 100, 'гр.'],['морковь', 50, 'гр.'],['огурцы', 50, 'гр.'],['горошек', 30, 'гр.'],['майонез', 70, 'мл.'],]
```

Данное блюдо необходимо приготовить на 3 человек, переменная `person = 3`.

Конечный список должен выглядеть так:

```
Салат:
картофель, 300гр.
морковь, 150гр.
огурцы, 150гр.
горошек, 90гр.
майонез, 210мл.
```

Comment: Добавили бы хоть один из кучи вариантов, которые пробовали.

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется хранить данные строго списками, то:

```
cook_book = [['салат', [['картофель', 100, 'гр.'],['морковь', 50, 'гр.'],['огурцы', 50, 'гр.'],['горошек', 30, 'гр.'],['майонез', 70, 'мл.']]]]
person = 3
for meal_instruction in cook_book:
    meal = meal_instruction[0]
    ingredients = meal_instruction[1]
    instruction = f'{meal.capitalize()}:\n' + '\n'.join(f'{i[0]}, {i[1]*person}{i[2]}' for i in ingredients)
print(instruction)
```

Comment: Данные нужно хранить в столбике, исправил описание. Прошу прощения, что сразу не указал этот факт.

Comment: Ну такую мелочь можно было бы и самому сделать, если цель научиться программировать :) Поправил ответ.